# SQL WHERE clause NOW() <= 4 months from now

Tags: sql

How would I write a query with a WHERE clause that basically is: `columnx <= Now() + 4 months`?

So basically `columnx` date range would have to be between today and 4 months from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server: `columnx <= DATEADD(mm,4,GETDATE())`

MySQL: `columnx <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 MONTHS)`

Comment: Hmm that would be why, i've been using DATEDIFF

Comment: DATEDIFF returns a timespan, DATEADD is the only one (of the two) that returns a date.

Comment: where (columnx>=GETDATE() and columnx<= DateADD(mm,4,GETDATE() fixed it

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Something
FROM SomeTable
WHERE columnx <= DATEADD(M, 4, GETDATE());
```